# How to find whether the word is present or not sqlite database android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am struggling with this scenario for past one week. I want to compare data base column value with this sentence like " San Francisco is located in US ". If any column has an " San Francisco ", it should be return that column .This is exactly what I want ? how can I do this ? please help me

Comment: Firstly show us what u have tried.

Comment: you can compare one column at a time

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you are looking for string_value like '%san fransico%'.This uses a wild card.

Answer (score 0):

In the query you must be using in the condition like some **string_value=some_value** So, there instead of using the "=" operator you have to use the like operator.

Comment: Hi Mr.Akash, Thank you for your response, but it didn't work for me and If I use "=" , it takes whole string and compare with sq lite value.Suppose if I use "like", It returns all the matches with exact match

Comment: Ya that's what you wanted right ?? In case of "San Francisco is located in US" if it gets "San Francisco" also it should return.